# Remove underline (bottom border) from MUI Input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can I remove these bottom-line borders from these inputs? I've tried throwing some CSS on it, but unsuccessfully component -> `<Input type={"text} />` ?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `disableUnderline` prop to true to hide the line below the [`Input`](https://mui.com/api/input/#:%7E:text=parent%20FormControl%20component.-,disableUnderline,-bool):

```
<Input disableUnderline
```